# Как обрабатывать запросы, содержащие слэши (/)?

Tags: java, spring

Проблема в следующем. URL запроса:(http://localhost:8080/login/verify/212,32,/cntv5tag07rmy791wbme7xa8x,/SSNZclzqhhH7v6uHIkUsIcPusKo=)

Мне нужно получить часть этого URL(**212,32,/cntv5tag07rmy791wbme7xa8x,/SSNZclzqhhH7v6uHIkUsIcPusKo=**).

К сожалению, поменять URL не представляется возможным, он формируется на стороне.

Моё решение не работает:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/verify/{request:.+}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
    public ResponseEntity verifyLogin(@PathVariable(value = "request") String request)
            throws InvalidSignatureException
    {
}
```

Ошибка: HTTP Status 404. Spring don't handle this request.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: Получите отдельно каждую часть @RequestMapping(value = "/login/verify/{request-1}/{request-2}/{request-3}/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json;charset=UTF-8"}) и получите эти переменные в методе

Comment: Дело в том что, 4 параметр это ключ, который может прийти в любой виде, в том числе и со слешем. К сожалению URL формирую не я и запрос приходит только в такой форме, и по этому нужно обработать этот вариант, желательно бескостыльным способом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обработать запрос без использования @PathVariable. Решение тут. @PathVariable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015637/how-to-handle-requests-that-contain-forward-slashes/44017419#44017419

Answer (score 1):

Как насчет?

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/login/verify/{nums}/{req1}/{req2}",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = { "application/json;charset=UTF-8" })
    public ResponseEntity verifyLogin(
        @PathVariable String nums,
        @PathVariable String req1,
        @PathVariable String req2)
            throws InvalidSignatureException
    {
}
```

Где у вас будет:

- `nums` = `"212,32,"`
- `param1` = `"cntv5tag07rmy791wbme7xa8x,"`
- `param2` = `"SSNZclzqhhH7v6uHIkUsIcPusKo="`

[Источник](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping) (п. 4.2)

Answer (score -1):

Можно из запроса получить данные(инжектится автоматически)

```
@RequestMapping("/login/verify/**")
void m1(HttpServlerRequest request){
  request.getServletPath()
  //по regex ищем нужную часть
}
```